# Ionic push - GCM_INVALID_AUTH

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm developing an Ionic (version 1.3.1) application and trying use Ionic push.
The application is correctly registering to ionic server but I still don't receive any notification in my device. The only error I get is the below notification status:

```
{
        "notification": "808cde89-eb21-40d7-9999-b86e5f86f1d3",
        "token": {
            "type": "android",
            "token": "dkYxYGcKeNo:APA91bE4OXhzkOUOSF1EsXxgY9Cd0Uu9-A98Ak5prdMIGUd10tLljacgKs7zAp1WPLF-bDiy3pkdroc9l8vWy4sXdfansr56-rIF59wJfR1e7EibJZHFO5DFxCThpT_ZgVn_T_0n8an1",
            "id": "ea40d3bc7561cc4f0d28ac49ce87fd3a",
            "app_id": "7ab91503",
            "invalidated": null,
            "created": "2016-09-17T11:31:53.481151+00:00",
            "valid": true
        },
        "uuid": "0ebe9454-aebc-4c0b-b5b0-056920817f56",
        "status": "error",
        "error": "GCM_INVALID_AUTH",
        "created": "2016-09-17T14:31:20.517783+00:00",
        "user_id": null
}
```

I'm supposing ionic server is not sending the notification to device as the status is error, but I don't know the reason why I'm getting this GCM_INVALID_AUTH error. What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need migrate your project from GCM to FCM (firebase cloud message) , and use new server key.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

I was using the wrong credentials from Google Cloud Platform. When I set to server key the problem was solved.